# Faking an installed PHP extension

Tags: php, phpstorm

I run a PHP app through Docker.  The container has the Newrelic extension installed.  I always run composer commands on the host machine; especially through the easy click access in PhpStorm.  Composer constantly complains that I do not have the newrelic extension installed.  On the command line, `--ignore-platform-reqs` is usable but tedious, in the GUI it is not possible.

Is there a way to make PHP expose the name of an extension that is not actually installed?  Or is there an easy way to compile an extension that does nothing?

Comment: You should run composer in the container. That is the only right way in my opinion.

Comment: ^^^ Above will keep everything in one place, so you don't have to worry about your scenario.

Comment: I can't run PhpStorm inside the container

Comment: FYI, you can actually [run commands in the docker container from PHP Storm.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/docker.html)

Answer (score 0):

there are several way
1.add "RUN  composer install " into your dockerfile or copy your composer.lock file inside docker on build time, in both cases you have rebuild the images

2.get inside running container using docker exec and run "composer install" i will resolve it for now.